# DoctrineExtensions Notice: Undefined index: foreignKey in $em->getRepository('Gedmo\\Translatable\\Entity\\Translation');

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I try to save multiple translations like in this [example](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#example-of-multiple-translations), but I have an error.

here is entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="BaseTranslation")
 * @ORM\Table(name="c_Base")
 */
class Base {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Hexaid
     * @var string
     */
    private $hid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @GRID\Column(title="name")
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

 /**
     * GRID\Column(title="translations",field="translations.content")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="BaseTranslation",
     *  mappedBy="object",
     *  cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     * @Assert\Valid(deep = true)
     */
    private $translations;
```

translation entity

```
/**
 * Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation.php

 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="c_base_translations",
 *   uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="lookup_unique_idx", columns={
 *     "locale", "object_id", "field"
 *   })}
 * )
 */
class BaseTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Base", inversedBy="translations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $object;

    public function __construct($locale, $field, $value)
    {
        $this->setLocale($locale);
        $this->setField($field);
        $this->setContent($value);
    }

}
```

i try use multiple translations

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('Gedmo\\Translatable\\Entity\\Translation');

        $article = new Base();

        $article->setName('content en');

        $repository->translate($article, 'name', 'de', 'name de')
            ->translate($article, 'name', 'pl', 'name pl')

        ;

        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();
```

and get

Notice: Undefined index: foreignKey

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: foreignKey
    at n/a
        in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php line 655

    at Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: foreignKey', '/home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php', '655', array('name' => 'foreignKey'))
        in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php line 655

    at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->getReflectionProperty('foreignKey')
        in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity/Repository/TranslationRepository.php line 80

    at Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository->translate(object(Base), 'name', 'de', 'name de')
        in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/vendor/Mea/CharterBundle/Controller/ResourcesController.php line 171

    at Mea\CharterBundle\Controller\ResourcesController->oneViewByHidAction('9888fff563a6a42', '2015;20')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(ResourcesController), 'oneViewByHidAction'), array('9888fff563a6a42', '2015;20'))
        in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3028

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2990

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3139

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2383

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/welasy/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: How you fixed this, bro? :) I have the same problem ;( [code identical to example https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#personal-translations ]

Answer (score 0):

add "@ORM\GeneratedValue" to Base

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
```

Comment: yes this was a litte bug but this is not reason. (i get part of code to show problem - bases dont have auto increment so i add id.) i update code in moment

Comment: I can only guess that the problem is related to "foreign key" of your tables, can you explore sql of tables and check do you have foreign key for tables relation?

Comment: i create new topic about version configuration in this example i have older version - please se here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272455/translation-form-with-default-entity-translations-not-found

Comment: in here example - https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#personal-translations dont have foreign key i dont know why