# translation-form with default entity translations not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-extensions

i try setup translations form

http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/ and https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#translatable-entity-example

composer.json

```
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "2.*@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
```

config.yml

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en
    orm:
        default:
            translatable: true
            sluggable: true
            sluggable: true
            timestampable: true

```
a2lix_translation_form:
    locale_provider: default       # [1]
    locales: [pl, en, de]          # [1-a]
    default_locale: en
    manager_registry: doctrine      # [2]
    templating: "A2lixTranslationFormBundle::default.html.twig"
```

entity

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use APY\DataGridBundle\Grid\Mapping as GRID;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="c_Base"
    ,indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="search_name", columns={"name"}),
 *      @ORM\Index(name="orderCity", columns={"city"})
 * })
 */
class Base  implements Translatable{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Hexaid
     * @var string
     */
    private $hid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @GRID\Column(title="name")
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     * Used locale to override Translation listener`s locale
     * this is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property
     */
    private $locale;
```

build form

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

```
    $builder

        ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', array(
                'fields'=>array(
                    'name'=>array(),
                    'description'=>array(
                        'field_type' => 'ckeditor'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

error

```
Neither the property "translations" nor one of the methods "getTranslations()", "translations()", "isTranslations()", "hasTranslations()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Mea\CharterBundle\Entity\Base".
```

i dont't have private $translations; var in base - because is public translation - in example for personal translations exist $translations 
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#personal-translations

but for https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#translatable-entity-example not.

Can i use it in http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/ ?

here is other way example 
[DoctrineExtensions Notice: Undefined index: foreignKey in $em->getRepository('Gedmo\\Translatable\\Entity\\Translation');](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263799/doctrineextensions-notice-undefined-index-foreignkey-in-em-getrepositoryge/30264649#30264649)

Comment: DoctrineExtensions from Atlantic18 is harder to use, better use DoctrineExtensions from KNP.. I can show an example if you want.

Comment: show example please, maybe i change i lost many time - i back to older version Atlantic18 and it work but sommetimes generate Undefined index: foreignKey

Comment: if you have interestig example yes. It have some form extension to edit translations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working example from my current project how to use DoctrineExtension from KNP (I know this doesn't answer the question, look at the comments above).

composer.json:

```
"knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "dev-master",
"a2lix/translation-form-bundle" : "dev-master"
```

config.yml:

```
imports:
    ...
    - { resource: ../../vendor/knplabs/doctrine-behaviors/config/orm-services.yml }

framework:
    translator:
        fallback: "%locale%"
    ...

a2lix_translation_form:
    locale_provider: default
    locales: [ru, en]
    default_locale: ru
    required_locales: [ru]
    manager_registry: doctrine
    templating: "@SLCore/includes/translation.html.twig" # if you want to use your own template
```

Entities:
Product

```
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\Translatable;

class Product
{
    use Translatable;

    // other fields which should not be translated
    // $translations field alredy has been created and mapped by DE
```

ProductTranslation (DE requires this entity):

```
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\Translation;

class ProductTranslation
{
    use Translation;

    // fields that should be translated
    // e.g. $title, $description (id, locale, translatable fields already have been created by Translation trait, mapped by DE)
```

ProductType form:

```
->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', [/* other options go here */])
```

form.html.twig:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/a2lixtranslationform/js/a2lix_translation_bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

...

{{ form_widget(form.translations) }}
```

I know this is not an interesting example, but it works.

Comment: Thank You for this example is good for my, i was not sure a2lix_translations, like you show it work with KNP